# Can't get the right resource in angularjs

Tags: django, angularjs, tastypie

I'm trying to set up a service that retrieves simple data from server but instead of returning the object I need it's returning a resource which I cannot query it.

Here is my code:

```
var subtitlesApp = angular.module('subtitlesApp', ['ngResource'])

subtitlesApp.factory('subtitleData', function ($resource) {
var resource = $resource('/api/v1/entry/:id/?format=json', {id:'@id'});
return {
    getSubtitle: function() {
        return resource.get({id:2});
    }
}
});

subtitlesApp.controller('SubtitleController', 
function SubtitleController($scope, subtitleData) {
$scope.subtitle = subtitleData.getSubtitle();
    console.log($scope.subtitle)
});
```

And here is what I get in return:

```
Resource {$get: function, $save: function, $query: function, $remove: function, $delete: function}

actors: ""
id: 2
imdb_id: "tt1535108"
plot_simple: ""
poster: ""
rating: 0
release_year: "2013"
resource_uri: "/api/v1/entry/2/"
slug: "elysium"
title: "Elysium"
trailer: ""
url: ""
__proto__: Resource
```

How I can get the object I need instead of the Resource object?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the response, and what do you want to get instead?

Comment: `Resource {actors: "", id: 2, imdb_id: "tt1535108", plot_simple: "", poster: ""…}` This is the object I'm expecting.

Comment: I don't get it. It seems like the object you get in return is the object you are expecting? Either that, or you aren't clear with your question.

Comment: I have the data but when I'm trying to access it, eg. subtitle.id I'm getting undefined :(

Comment: ngResource and Tastypie (and Django REST Framework for that matter) simply do not play ball together in my experience. I've switched to Restangular myself.